# Swift- Segue to UITabBarController page from ViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `UITabViewController` in my app. On the third `ViewController` of the `UITabViewController`, the user is able to go to a separate `ViewController` outside of the `UITabViewController`. But, when they segue back, the `UITabView` bar doesn't show. So, I made a segue back to the `UITabViewController` but now it just goes to the first page of the `UITabViewController` instead of the 3rd. I have a prepareForSegue() on the separate `ViewController` file telling it to go to the 3rd page but it doesn't seem to be working. Here is my code:

```
func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if(segue.identifier == "tabBarShow"){
        if let tabVC = segue.destination as? UITabBarController {
            tabVC.selectedIndex = 2
            let tabBarController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarC‌​ontroller") as! UITabBarController
            tabBarController.selectedViewController = tabBarController.viewControllers![2]
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to solve this? Any help would be immensely appreciated. Thanks so much in advance!!

Cheers, Theo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
@IBAction func backTouched(sender: AnyObject) {
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

linking that up in the controller you want to dismiss? Or using the func unWindToSegue(segue: ...) method?